# Entropy due to iron block on the universe?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

Suppose we have two objects made of iron, one hot the other colder. What happens to the entropy of universe when we bring them in contact, will it increase or decrease? Why? How can we prove that using second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: If you could show that, with the two blocks isolated from the rest of the universe, their entropy would increase after they equilibrated, would this convince you that the overall entropy of the universe increased?

Comment: Indeed it would simplify the question considerably if you would leave out the universe. The concept of the entropy of the universe is controversial, see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe

Comment: Thank you @my2cts, but I would like to hear what the OP has to say about this.

Comment: @Chester my comment was directed at the OP. Nevertheless, the assertion that the entropy of the universe is a controversial  notion also is relevant to your comment.

Comment: @my2cts My interpretation of the OP's question was whether the process between the two objects contributed an increase to the entropy of the universe.  In the context he was using, the "universe" was regarded as the system (the two blocks) plus the immediate surroundings (all together comprising an "isolated system").

Comment: @Chester That is a very free interpretation of the word. Too free.

Comment: @my2cts That may very well be, but that is how the term "universe" is typically used in beginning thermodynamics courses.